# Facebook share javascript SDK v3.x using Iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

Facebook sharing using feed or share has a success call back and can tell if user shared or not, but when using iframe it allways says that the user canceled the dialog `{error_code: 4201, error_message: "User+canceled+the+Dialog+flow"}`and cant tell if the user shared or not, but same function without the use of iframe is working properly

```
function sharfeToFacebook() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var options = {
            method: 'share',
            mobile_iframe: true,
            href: photoUrl,
        };
        FB.ui(options, function(response) {
            console.log('FB share dialog started with response: ', response);
            if (response && !response.error_code) {
                // fb does returns an emtpy object on success, undefined when fail or canceled
                deferred.resolve(response);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: _“and can tell if user shared or not”_ - why would you need that? The user themselves gets feedback from the dialog already; and rewarding users for sharing, or gating content behind a “forced” share, is absolutely not allowed …

Comment: i need it because i want to log shared content from my website, and i want to log successfully shared content, and its applicable when not using Iframe, and i have to use iframe becaue i have two popups(app login and share) and i only can use one because it needs to be initiated by user(trusted) and thats why i have to use iframe, also browser such as safari and mozilla blocks untrusted popups by default.

Comment: Popups should only get blocked by default, if they are not directly connected to a user interaction (click on a link/ button), or if you nest the call into something asynchronous.

Comment: That's why I'm stuck with the iframe scenario, because the first popup(trusted) is the app login popup

Comment: So you are trying to handle both - app login and sharing - by just one click? Why? Is this sharing the main purpose of your app?

Comment: the sharing and logging are the purpose of the app, and the user must login to the app to be able to share, and for a better user experience i made it a one click scenario, so it switches from popup to iframe base if he is already logged or not

Comment: @yousef did you find a solution?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah unfortunately no